# More visible space in mc (Midnight Commander) for command lines

Tags: midnight-commander

I want more space as shown here:

[image: image of monitor with midnight commander full screen]

Default mc with active panels has only one line where the user can type commands, I want to see more console output without pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> pressing.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options here:

- Try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. And forget your FAR, VC and NC :)
- It seems that functionality is already here: press <kbd>F9</kbd> (or *Options*), select *Layout* and find *Console output* here. It works in native Linux console (plain VT, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) on 12.04 LTS, 17.04, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS, but not on 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS. There are [upstream bug](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3655) and [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mc/+bug/1738535) about that.

Comment: Yes, I know this hotkey. My mistake, that I confused far and mc ...
Thanks for answer.

Comment: It works on plain VTs on 17.10 and 18.04 LTS - see updated answer above.

Comment: In case it is not clear: this can ONLY work in a VT, NOT in a X terminal like gnome-terminal or Mac's Terminal.app. MC's [bug #2955](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2955) about this is marked as "wontfix"